# Get RepositoryItem (As Control) From Devexpress-GridviewCell

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I'm using the `devexpress Gridcontrol/Gridview` which has 4 columns

```
Name: String
Description: String
Action: RepositoryItemLookUpEdit
Info: RepositoryItemHyperLinkEdit
```

Right now i want to write a function which `updates` the `Action-column` but only if the `Value` is contained in the `datasource` of the `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit`

So i started writing the code and this is how i far i got:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridViewDD.RowCount - 1
    Dim j As Integer = i
    Dim rItemlookup As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = CType(GridViewDD.GetRow(i), DataRowView).Item("Actions")
    If CType(rItemlookup.DataSource, List(Of String)).Contains(curraction) Then
         // Do update of the datasource here (which works)
    End If
Next

GridControlDD.RefreshDataSource()
```

My problem lies at the line:

```
Dim rItemlookup As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = CType(GridViewDD.GetRow(i), DataRowView).Item("Actions")
```

**Question:**
How can i get the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit of a cell in devexpress (or its datasource)?

**Note:**
The datasource of my gridview (`GridViewDD`) is a `List` And my datasource of the `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit` in `Action` is always a `List(Of String)`

**Note 2:**
The `contents` of my `datasource may vary` from row to row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get your `RepositoryItem` from [`GridColumn.ColumnEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_ColumnEdittopic) property.
Here is example:

```
Dim rItemlookup As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = GridViewDD.Columns("Action").ColumnEdit

'...

For i As Integer = 0 To GridViewDD.RowCount - 1
    Dim j As Integer = i

    If CType(rItemlookup.DataSource, List(Of String)).Contains(curraction) Then
         '... Do update of the datasource here (which works)
    End If
Next

GridControlDD.RefreshDataSource()
```

Comment: Waaah! Even better then my own solution! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. thanks to 'many' hours of browsing the devexpress-forums. Using [Gridviewinfo](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseControl_GetViewInfotopic) and `GridDataRowInfo` you can easily access the controls 'hidden' inside the grid

In my case the code looks as following

```
Dim gvInfo As GridViewInfo = GridViewDD.GetViewInfo()
Dim rInfo As GridDataRowInfo = gvInfo.RowsInfo.FindRow(i)
Dim rItemlookup As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = rInfo.Cells(GridViewDragDrop.Columns.Item("Actions")).Editor
```

you can now use `rItemlookup` to change or access its properties.

I hope this may be of some use to anyone.